# Adding Dll to Subversion from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to SVN though I have used TFS previously. I have ASP.Net project in VS 2010. I need to add AjaxControlToolkit dll to the project. After adding this dll, I tried to commit the changes using Subversion in VS2010. The project file appears in the list of items to commit; however the newly added dll is not listed. How can I check in the newly added dll too?

Note: I am looking for an approach involving User Interface actions; not commands. I am using Tortoise SVN

Note: BIN folder has a question mark. The dll is added into that as well. So, am I supposed to checkin the BIN? There is no questionmark for the dll file inside the BIN folder too

Comment: Is the dll file in the working copy tree?

Comment: Right-click file in Windows Explorer > Tortoise SVN > Add -- if this is not possible, then the file is not in the working copy tree.

Comment: The file should have a question mark in a blue circle if it has not been added yet, not an exclamation mark in a red circle.

Comment: The "References" folder in Visual Studio does not represent a directory on your hard disk. If you add an assembly reference to a project, the assembly stays where it is; Visual Studio just adds a reference to it.

Comment: You need to copy the dll file to the working copy. You can't check in files that are not in the working copy. Do not check in the Bin directory; you should svn:ignore that.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a "Lib" folder and keep the file there in working copy and then refer it from there?

Comment: Yes, creating a directory in the working copy and putting all third-party dll files in there sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

Create an "ExternalDlls" folder in your projects root folder. Place external dll's (like AjaxControlToolkit.dll) in this ExternalDlls folder. Add this folder and it's contained dll's to SVN using TortoiseSVN's Add.

Now add a reference to your external dll from within Visual Studio. You should be able to right click the "References" folder and add a reference. There will be an option to "Browse" your file system. Browse to the "ExternalDlls" folder and find the dll you want to add, in this case the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Select the dll and add it to the references.

OK - so now you should have the DLL added to your references, and an ExternalDlls folder ready to commit to SVN!

A suggestion:
Checkout [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) if you are looking for Visual Studio SVN integration. You can also check out [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/), but you will have to pay for it. These are nice tools to have handy and allow you to handle SVN actions directly from Visual Studio. VisualSVN is smart enough not to add unnecessary files as well.

Comment: I have created a "Lib" folder and keep the file there in working copy and then refered it from there